# Android: ZipFile, FileNotFoundException when use Assets Files

Tags: android, file, zip, assets

I have a problem.

I use this code to read the content of a zip file:

```
    File file = new File(TogglesManager.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_THEMES_DIRECTORY+"filename.zip");
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
```

But when I try to use an assets I have a `FileNotFoundException`.

To read asset zip file I use this code:

```
    File file = c.getFileStreamPath("assetsFile.zip");
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
```

The "file" is not null, because if I write `file.getName();` I see the correct file name.

I don't want to use `ZipInputStream` class, but only `ZipFile`

Comment: Maybe you answer is in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: Many thanks but I just tried these solutions...

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11615158/794088

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access Assets using normal file operations. You will have to use

```
AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("assetsFile.zip");
```

But since ZipFile does not take InputStream as a parameter, you will have to copy asset file onto internal storage and then use `File`

Further AFAIK, apk is zipped, so storing a zipped file inside assets might not change storage used by much, so maybe you donot need to use zipfile inside assets.

Comment: Many thanks..there is another way instead of ZipFile or ZipInputStream to read Zip file without extract it?

Comment: I am not too sure, but ZipInputStream should do the job using InputStream that you have got from assetManager.open

Comment: `Further AFAIK, apk is zipped, so storing a zipped file inside assets might not change storage used by much, so maybe you donot need to use zipfile inside assets.` Confirmed & Thanks

Comment: can you confirm the validity of the statement @MuhammadBabar

Comment: @Killer as APK is itself zipped so bundled files will automatically be zipped. But Sorry as the thread is quite old so I can't confirm the validity. BTW you can verify it yourself by adding files both zipped and unzipped and check the size.