# How to deal with loads of small files in android

Tags: android

I have been working on a dictionary App, but I was stuck in adding pronunciations to each word.
There are about 40,000 tiny mp3 files in my App, I put them in the asset folder, and it's always failed when I try to run my app. I googled for a while, there is no hint for solving this kind of problem.
Is there anyone could give me a hint to solving this problem, just a key word would still help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11615158/794088 might help

Comment: What is the problem, logcat please?